# Java: How can I ignore tags prefixes

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, post, xml-namespaces

Having the following xml as a post parameter how can I ignore "v1:" or "typ:" namespaces so I can map each tag to a Java class?
I want to create an object from this kind of xml but I'm having an error because of the namespaces before the tags (without them is working fine but I can't change the XML).

**Java controller method is:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/XML", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<GetCompanyStructureDetailsResponseContent> getXml(@RequestBody GetCompanyStructureDetailsRequest request){
  // how should I filter this XML....
return null;
    }
```

**XML at request is:**

```
<v1:getCompanyStructureDetailsRequest>
  <v1:trackingInformation>
        <typ:eventLocalID>234233423434234234</typ:eventLocalID>
        <typ:applicationID>MSD</typ:applicationID>
        <typ:originApplicationID>MSD</typ:originApplicationID> 
  </v1:trackingInformation>
  <v1:getCompanyStructureDetailsRequestContent>
    <v1:customer>
      <v1:organizationIdentifier>
        <v1:companyIndex>33503</v1:companyIndex>
      </v1:organizationIdentifier>
    </v1:customer>
  </v1:getCompanyStructureDetailsRequestContent>
</v1:getCompanyStructureDetailsRequest>
```

**Error is:**

```
w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not unmarshal to [class com.example.dto.request.GetCompanyStructureDetailsRequest]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 39; The prefix "v1" for element "v1:getCompanyStructureDetailsRequest" is not bound.]
```

Comment: When dealing with XML you also have to deal with namespaces. There is nothing too special or too complicated with that mechanism. Libraries that parse XML have to take care of namespaces (and prefixes). Having said this: The above XML is syntactically invalid. Don't bend the XML parsing tool, but correct the XML!

Comment: To add to what @Seelenvirtuose said, the most relevant parts missing from the xml are the actual namespaces that are actually represented by the `v1` and `typ` prefixes.

Comment: I need to somehow configure the parser to ignore the prefixes. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: You're so stuck on *ignoring* that you're ignoring the sound advice that you've received from at least 5 people trying to help you by telling you that you ***should not ignore XML namespaces***.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it, first some POJOs:

```
@XmlName("v1:getCompanyStructureDetailsRequest")
public class GetCompanyStructureDetailsRequest {
    @XmlName("v1:trackingInformation")
    public TrackingInformation tracking;
    @XmlName("v1:getCompanyStructureDetailsRequestContent")
    public CompanyStructure structure;
}
public class TrackingInformation {
    @XmlName("typ:eventLocalID")
    public String eventLocalID;
    @XmlName("typ:applicationID")
    public String applicationID;
    @XmlName("typ:originApplicationID")
    public String originApplicationID;
}
public class CompanyStructure {
    @XmlName("v1:customer")
    public Customer customer;
}
public class Customer {
    @XmlWrapperTag("v1:organizationIdentifier")
    @XmlName("v1:companyIndex")
    public Integer companyId;
}
```

Then serialize and print:

```
public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
    final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
    final GetCompanyStructureDetailsRequest r = simple.fromXml(xml, GetCompanyStructureDetailsRequest.class);
    System.out.println(r.structure.customer.companyId);
}
```

This code will print:

```
33503
```

SimpleXml is in maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```